# Can Google Cloud Messaging be implemented on godaddy shared webserver?

Tags: php, android

Can Google Cloud Messaging be implemented on godaddy shared webserver using php?

EDIT:

May anybody point me out on how to do so? Like an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can run the backend on any shared hoster.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @diosney This *does* provide an answer to the question.  The asker only asked, if it's possible or not. He didn't ask for any other assistance regarding that matter. If jasa was expecting an answer with a code sample, then he/she should have asked differently.

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks for the answer! I'll have to investigate on how to proceed, though.